# getting data from cassandra using clauses

Tags: php, cassandra, phpcassa

Is there any way to get data from cassandra through `phpcassa` using a clauses?

I need to select all rows where `sum<10`. For example the function in phpcassa `get_range()`  selects only rows which equals certain values.

Comment: i found the solution
There needs to use `cassandra_IndexOperator` when creating index expression

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally with PHPCassa, you would use indexes:

As per http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/tutorial.html // slightly enhanced:

```
<?php
$column_family = new ColumnFamily($conn, 'Indexed1');
$index_exp_eq = CassandraUtil::create_index_expression('gender', 'male', $op='EQ');
$index_exp_gt = CassandraUtil::create_index_expression('sum', 10, $op='GT');
$index_clause = CassandraUtil::create_index_clause(array($index_exp_eq, $index_exp_gt));
$rows = $column_family->get_indexed_slices($index_clause);
// returns an Iterator over:
//    array('winston smith' => array('birthdate' => 1984))

foreach($rows as $key => $columns) {
    // Do stuff with $key and $columns
    Print_r($columns)
}
?>
```

With your scenario, you cannot simply have a single index expression with sum<10 ... You must have the first index expression with an EQ operator and subsequent index expressions with other Operators.

Comment: but if a haven't any columns which is equal to any data that i have?